# nm-applet "Enable wifi" option greyed out

Tags: debian, networkmanager

Since I updated my machine today, it is not possible to click "Enable networking" or "Enable wifi" in the nm-applt. It seems to be a permission problem because if I launch nm-applet as root, there is no issue.

It already happened in the past but adding myself to the `netdev` group solved the problem. This time however, I don't find a solution...

Additional info:

- Debian 9.2
- network-manager 1.6.2-3

Additional info requested by GAD3R:

```
$ tail /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop
Icon=nm-device-wireless
Exec=nm-applet
Terminal=false
Type=Application
NoDisplay=true
NotShowIn=KDE;GNOME;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=NetworkManager
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=nm-applet
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
```

Comment: My guess: you somehow managed to get some files owned by root. please check with the following command (feel free to [edit] your question to show the result): `find ~ -not -user $USER -ls`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I only get a bunch of scripts I made owned by root. Nothing unusual on this side.

Comment: What is the output of `tail /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop`  [edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/401727/edit)

Comment: Edited in question

Comment: and the output of `nmcli general permissions` as user

Comment: Found the issue. Thanks for your help. See the answer bellow for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking the permission (Thanks GAD3R!) with

```
$ nmcli general permissions
PERMISSION                                                 VALUE 
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network      no   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wifi         no
```

I found out that I had not the permissions to enable wifi or networking.

These permissions are set trough polkit in this file:

```
/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.policy
```

Last things to do was set the keys given above by replacing

```
<allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
```

to

```
<allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>
```

If I understood right, the `inactive` here refers to a remote session which is not my case. The reason for this can be that I'm not using any display manager.

Comment: Weird.  Both of these say "yes" for me, and they are both enabled.  Problem is, I can't *disable* them (WiFi specifically)

Answer (score 0):

This can caused by running in a remote session (e.g. XRDP). A workaround is to use:

```
sudo -E nm-connection-editor
```

This runs it at root, but keeps the original user's environment variables, so that NM can open the display.